# MongoDB : aggregate value from two arrays in document (mapping)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

Am new to MongoDB and I have two arrays in a document like this. I want to get a specific value from both arrays. For example "received_bytes" and its value from the values array "43118304". I did some research but I think am lost.

```
fields:{
 "time",
 "received_bytes",
 "sent_bytes"
}
values:{
 "2021-11-22T08:08:30Z",
 43118304,
 43105744
}
```

Basic aggregate I have done

```
return await Metric.aggregate([
  {
    $match: matches,
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: params.field, // received_bytes
      values: { $push: '$values' }, // array of values for received_bytes
    },
  },
]);
```

What i expect:

```
{
  _id:"received_bytes",
  values:[] //all received_bytes values
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you can give valid JSON data and the expected output

Comment: @Takis_ Its already real json data.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find best answer so I grouped the results then loop on them to get my values

```
 const metrics = await Metric.aggregate([
  {
    $match: matches,
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  // mapping fields=>values where field equal to params.field
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$fields',
      values: { $push: '$values' },
    },
  },
]);
```